# Custom Image Slider not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, flexbox

I'm trying to create an image slider, problem is I can't seem to loop through my images's divs…

I thought about creating an array containing all the divs and looping through them, but I don't know how to do this…

Furthermore, I needed to center, vertically and horizontally align the images in their respective div, which I usually use flexbox to do so, but in what I have, I cant really use flexbox. Can you guys take a look at what I have and maybe help me out?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slider = $('.slider-tile');
  var one = slider.first().addClass('active');

  $('.next').click(function() {
    var currentActive = slider.filter(".active");
    var nextNumber = currentActive.next();
    if (nextNumber.hasClass("hidden")) {
      currentActive.removeClass("active").addClass('hidden');
      nextNumber.removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");

      if ($('.slider-tile').last().hasClass('active')) {
        $(currentActive).removeClass('active');
        $('.slider-tile').first().addClass('active').removeClass('hidden');
      }

    }
  });

  $(".prev").click(function() {
    var currentActive = slider.filter(".active");
    var prevNumber = currentActive.prev();
    if (prevNumber.hasClass("hidden")) {
      currentActive.removeClass("active").addClass('hidden');
      prevNumber.removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #a2a2a2;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.slider-tile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}
.slider-tile img {
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-tile">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/8c2b8c/ffffff" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="slider-tile hidden">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/540154/ffffff" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="slider-tile hidden">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/8c2b8c/ffffff" alt="" />
  </div>

</div>
<button class="prev">
  <</button>
    <button class="next">></button>
```

and here is the [PEN](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/JbwpVg) I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next/previous navigation script can be modified to something like this:

(While going *next* from the last slide, you can go back to the first and the other way around while going *prev* from the first slide)

```
  $('.next').click(function() {
    var currentActive = slider.filter(".active");
    currentActive.removeClass("active").addClass('hidden');
    if (currentActive.is(slider.last())) {
      slider.first().removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");
    } else {
      currentActive.next().removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");
    }
  });

  $(".prev").click(function() {
    var currentActive = slider.filter(".active");
    currentActive.removeClass("active").addClass('hidden');
    if (currentActive.is(slider.first())) {
      slider.last().removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");
    } else {
      currentActive.prev().removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");
    }
  });
```

You can as well create a `flexbox` for the *active* slide like:

```
.slider-tile.active {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slider = $('.slider-tile');
  var one = slider.first().addClass('active');

  $('.next').click(function() {
    var currentActive = slider.filter(".active");
    currentActive.removeClass("active").addClass('hidden');
    if (currentActive.is(slider.last())) {
      slider.first().removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");
    } else {
      currentActive.next().removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");
    }


  });

  $(".prev").click(function() {
    var currentActive = slider.filter(".active");
    currentActive.removeClass("active").addClass('hidden');
    if (currentActive.is(slider.first())) {
      slider.last().removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");
    } else {
      currentActive.prev().removeClass('hidden').addClass("active");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #a2a2a2;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.slider-tile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}
.slider-tile img {
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.slider-tile.active {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-tile">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/8c2b8c/ffffff" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="slider-tile hidden">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/540154/ffffff" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="slider-tile hidden">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/8c2b8c/ffffff" alt="" />
  </div>

</div>
<button class="prev">
  <</button>
    <button class="next">></button>
```